# I am trying to pass values from a string stored in an apex class to Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to pass values from a string(finalResponse) stored in an apex class to Visualforce page. I am receiving the 
Error: Unknown property 'EM_Object_vod__cStandardController.finalResponse'

**VF Page**

```
      <apex:page showChat="false" showHeader="false" standardController="EM_Object_vod__c" extensions="Hello_Speaker_CA" showQuickActionVfHeader="true" pageStyle="Email"

      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Target.size > 0 }">

      <td> <apex:outputLabel value="{!finalResponse}"/>/></b></td>
```

**Apex class**

```
     public class Hello_Speaker_CA {
     public List<Target_vod__c> Target {get;set;}
     public List<Response_vod__c>Response {get;set;}

     public Hello_Speaker_CA(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    try {

        actionBtn=true;
        Target = new List<Target_vod__c>();
        Response = new List<Response_vod__c>();
        String finalResponse;  
        EM_Object_vod__c referenceId = (EM_Object_vod__c)controller.getRecord();
        Target = [SELECT id FROM Target_vod__c WHERE Status_vod__c ='Saved'];
        for(Response_vod__c response: [Select 
        Question_vod__c,Response_vod__c,Number_vod__c FROM Response_vod__c
        where Target_vod__c IN:Target]){                                     
        if(response.Response_vod__c !=null)
        {
         finalResponse = response.Response_vod__c;
          }
        else if (response.Number_vod__c !=null)
        {
         String value1=String.ValueOf(response.Number_vod__c);
         finalResponse = value1;
         }
```

Can you please explain why I am receiving the above error even after using standard controller with extensions in VF page? And the best possible way to pass the string finalResponse to VF page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your string "finalResponse" outside the method and make it a get;set; variable only then you can use it in your VF Page

```
public class Hello_Speaker_CA {
 public List<Target_vod__c> Target {get;set;}
 public List<Response_vod__c>Response {get;set;}
**public string finalResponse {get;set;}**

 public Hello_Speaker_CA(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

try {
    **finalResponse = '';**
    actionBtn=true;
    Target = new List<Target_vod__c>();
    Response = new List<Response_vod__c>();
    **//String finalResponse;**  
    EM_Object_vod__c referenceId = (EM_Object_vod__c)controller.getRecord();
    Target = [SELECT id FROM Target_vod__c WHERE Status_vod__c ='Saved'];
    for(Response_vod__c response: [Select 
    Question_vod__c,Response_vod__c,Number_vod__c FROM Response_vod__c
    where Target_vod__c IN:Target]){                                     
    if(response.Response_vod__c !=null)
    {
     finalResponse = response.Response_vod__c;
      }
    else if (response.Number_vod__c !=null)
    {
     String value1=String.ValueOf(response.Number_vod__c);
     finalResponse = value1;
     }
```

Try this and let me know if it helps